BeanUtils getProperty not working for record
If my object is a record this is not working :
value = BeanUtils.getProperty(object, property);

I guess it is looking for a getter which does not exist.
Is there an alternative for java 17, that will work for classes and record ?

There’s always value = object instanceof Record ? object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(property).invoke(object) : BeanUtils.getProperty(object, property);
